# Powerpoint fullscreen remove black frame

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

When I activate slideshow mode in Powerpoint 2011 for mac, my slides get a black frame around them.

Is it possible to remove this black frame and stretch the slide to fit to the screen?

NOTE: If it's not possible, can I at least change the color of the frame?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to change the slide size, which will remove the black edges.

1. The method mentioned at the end of techturtle's answer works.

> According to [this document](http://www.esm.rochester.edu/esmtmp/files/MicrosoftPowerpoint2011.pdf) (page 12), the steps in the 2011 version are to go to the Themes tab, and click on Slide Size in the Page Setup group.

2. The following method will also work. Go to *File -> Page Setup...* and look at the section titled *Size*. Depending on the aspect ratio ([definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio)) of your monitor, one of the following options should get rid of the black edges:

   - On-screen Show (4:3)
   - On-screen Show (16:9)
   - On-screen Show (16:10)

Note that changing the size of your slides may result in items no longer being centered or placed as expected, so you may have to reformat slides afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar situation.  I can't say that this will work exactly, since I have PowerPoint 2010 for Windows, but the problem I have faced was that the default presentation size was not fit right for my monitor.  By default, PowerPoint uses a 4:3 screen layout for new presentations.  Changing this to match your screen size and shape should remove the black edges.  In the 2010 version it is on the `Design tab`, on the option for `Page Setup`.  According to [this document](http://www.esm.rochester.edu/esmtmp/files/MicrosoftPowerpoint2011.pdf) (page 12), the steps in the 2011 version are to go to the `Themes` tab, and click on `Slide Size` in the `Page Setup` group.